# Role on mongodb - can insert even the user is not authorized

Tags: mongodb

I create 2 db, and one user per db, but user 2 can insert in db1?

```
use shop
db.createUser({user: "appdev",pwd:"appdev", roles:["readWrite"]})
db.auth("appdev","appdev")
show collections
db.products.insertOne({name: "A book for appdev"})

db.logout()

use shop2
db.createUser({user: "appdev2",pwd:"appdev2", roles:["readWrite"]})
db.auth("appdev2","appdev2")
show collections
db.products.insertOne({name: "A book for appdev2"})
```

Here, I still logged as appdev2 and can insert on db shop.

```
use shop
db.products.insertOne({name:"i-am-appdev2"})
{
    "acknowledged" : true,
    "insertedId" : ObjectId("5d8fdba878f7555a2060f1ec")
}
```

Comment: If your transcript is accurate, it looks like like either you haven't [enabled access control](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security.authorization) (by setting `security.authorization` to `true` in your `mongod` config) or are logged in as a more privileged user (since you are able to run `db.createUser()` in the same session). You can check if  `authorization` is enabled via the output of ` db.serverCmdLineOpts().parsed`.

Comment: @Stennie Work thanks!, can you add as answer to mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your transcript is accurate, it looks like like either:

- You haven't [enabled access control](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security.authorization) by setting `security.authorization` to `true` in your mongod config or starting `mongod` with `--auth`.
- You are logged in as a more privileged user (since you are able to run `db.createUser()` in the same session).

To investigate these possibilities in the `mongo` shell:

- Make sure `authorization` is enabled via the output of `db.serverCmdLineOpts()`. If access control is enabled, the output of the `parsed` server configuration options should include a section like:

```
    "security" : {
        "authorization" : "enabled"
    },
```

- Check users & roles for the current session via `db.runCommand({connectionStatus:1})`. As noted in [Authenticate a User](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-users/#authenticate-a-user):

  > Authenticating multiple times as different users does not drop the credentials of previously-authenticated users. This may lead to a connection having more permissions than intended by the user, and causes operations within a logical session to raise an error.

Access control is a separate option from configuring Role-Based Access Control (RBAC) to allow for scenarios like resetting admin access. Multiple concurrent logins provide additive permissions, but are mostly a legacy carryover from more simplistic versions of access control in earlier versions of MongoDB.

For more information on available security measures, see the [Security Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/) in the MongoDB manual.